# Looking for Confirmation About Pythagorean Answers

Tags: triangles

> $$\tan{\theta} = x$$ $\theta$ is in quadrant 2.  Find values of the other 5 trig functions.

My confusion is about $x$ having to be negative because of the $-x$ value, even though it says "$x$".

$\sin{\theta} = \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

$\cos{\theta} = \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$

$\tan{\theta} = x$

csc = (x^2+1)^.5/x

sec = (x^2+1)^.5

cot = 1/x

Comment: $\theta$ is in quadrant 2 which means $\sin$, $\csc$ are positive and $\cos$, $\sec$, $\tan$ and $\cot$ are negative. If $\tan \theta =x$, then $\sin \theta=-\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

Comment: so everything would be the opposite of what it normally would be?

Comment: What do you mean by "normal",  anony? If $\theta$ is in quadrant 2, then $\tan\theta<0$, so $x$ is negative, and the correct formulas follow from that observation.

Comment: Your issue is a cognitive dissonance occurring because you are thinking of $x$ as in $x$ and $y$ coordinates and the unit circle. But that is not at all how $x$ is being used here. I strongly suggest that you solve this by saying $\tan \theta = t$ instead of $x$. Then $x$ and $y$ are free to take their familiar roles in your thinking. Once you've found all the values in terms of $t$, change the variable in the expressions back from $t$ to $x$.